# How to generate XML from an object without indentation using nokogiri-happymapper and roxml

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, indentation

I started using [nokogiri-happymapper](https://github.com/dam5s/happymapper) and [roxml](https://github.com/Empact/roxml) to convert Ruby objects to XML. I am not able to generate XML without indentation ("\n") and without instruction.

Is there an option to set `:indent=>0, :skip_instruct` for the `to_xml` method, as we have for [Active Support](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/4.2.5.1/Hash#to_xml-instance_method) in nokogiri-happymapper and roxml?

Also, when I try to convert the XML to an object using [roxml](https://github.com/Empact/roxml), I get a string containing `@roxml_references`. How can I correctly convert XML to Ruby object?

The ROXML code is:

```
require 'roxml'
class Book
  include ROXML

  xml_accessor :isbn
  xml_accessor :title
  xml_accessor :description
  xml_accessor :author
end

book = Book.new
book.author = "ABC"
book.title = "Ruby"
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
doc.root = book.to_xml
puts doc.to_s
```

which outputs:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<book>\n  <title>Ruby</title>\n  <author>ABC</author>\n</book>\n"
```

And:

```
obj = Book.from_xml(doc.to_s)
puts obj
```

which outputs:

```
#<Mod::Book:0x00000003141718 @author="ABC", @title="Ruby", @roxml_references=[#<ROXML::XMLTextRef:0x00000003141650 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition
:0x000000031b93f8 @default=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrapper=nil, @namespace=nil, @ac
cessor="isbn", @array=false, @blocks=[], @sought_type=:text, @attr_name="isbn", @name="isbn">, @instance=#<Mod::Book:0x00000003141718 ...>,
  @default_namespace=nil>, #<ROXML::XMLTextRef:0x00000003141628 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition:0x000000031b8930 @default=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_ex
  plicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrapper=nil, @namespace=nil, @accessor="title", @array=false, @blocks=[], @sought_typ
e=:text, @attr_name="title", @name="title">, @instance=#<Mod::Book:0x00000003141718 ...>, @default_namespace=nil>, #<ROXML::XMLTextRef:0x000
  00003141600 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition:0x000000031a3fa8 @default=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=n
  il, @wrapper=nil,
```

The nokogiri-happymapper code is:

```
require 'happymapper'

class Book
  include HappyMapper

  attr_accessor :title,:author
  tag 'book'
  element :title, String, :tag => 'title'
  element :author, String, :tag => 'author'
end

book = Mod::Book.new
book.author = "ABC"
book.title = "Ruby"

xml_obj = book.to_xml
p xml_obj
```

which outputs:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<book>\n  <title>Ruby</title>\n  <author>ABC</author>\n</book>\n"
```

And:

```
obj = Mod::Book.parse(xml_obj)
p obj
```

which outputs:

```
#<Mod::Book:0x00000000661cf0 @author="ABC", @title="Ruby">
```

How can I remove the indentation when generating XML from an object, along with the XML instruction for both approaches?

I have tried following approaches :
Approach 1:

```
 xml =  Nokogiri::XML(xml_obj).to_xml(:save_with =>  Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::AS_XML | Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION)
 p xml
```

which outputs

```
"<book>\n  <title>Ruby</title>\n  <author>ABC</author>\n</book>\n"
```

Approach 2:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(xml_obj, nil,nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::NOBLANKS).root.to_s
p xml
```

which outputs

```
"<book>\n  <title>Ruby</title>\n  <author>ABC</author>\n</book>"
```

I am using below approach to convert object to xml in roxml :

```
xml_obj = lib.to_xml.to_xml(:save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::AS_XML)
p xml_obj
```

which outputs :

```
"<Library><author><name>Shruti</name></author><book><title>RoR</title></book></Library>"
```

Now when I try to convert xml back to object it gives me an additional instance variable @roxml_references as below :

```
obj = Library.from_xml(xml_obj)
p obj
```

which outputs :

```
#<Library:0x00000002a1ebc0 @author=#<Author:0x00000002a1c780 @name="Shruti", @roxml_references=[#<ROXML::XMLTextRef:0x00000002a1e1e8 @opts=#
<ROXML::Definition:0x00000002a46418 @default=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrapper=nil, @
namespace=nil, @accessor="name", @array=false, @blocks=[], @sought_type=:text, @attr_name="name", @name="name">, @instance=#<Author:0x000000
02a1c780 ...>, @default_namespace=nil>]>, @book=[#<Book:0x00000002a08e60 @title="RoR", @roxml_references=[#<ROXML::XMLTextRef:0x00000002a092
e8 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition:0x00000002a3e8d0 @default=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrap
per=nil, @namespace=nil, @accessor="title", @array=false, @blocks=[], @sought_type=:text, @attr_name="title", @name="title">, @instance=#<Bo
ok:0x00000002a08e60 ...>, @default_namespace=nil>, #<ROXML::XMLTextRef:0x00000002a09400 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition:0x00000002a3d6b0 @default=
nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrapper=nil, @namespace=nil, @accessor="description", @arra
y=false, @blocks=[], @sought_type=:text, @attr_name="description", @name="description">, @instance=#<Book:0x00000002a08e60 ...>, @default_na
mespace=nil>], @description=nil>], @roxml_references=[#<ROXML::XMLObjectRef:0x00000002a1eb20 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition:0x00000002a3c080 @def
ault=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrapper=nil, @namespace=nil, @accessor="author", @arra
y=false, @blocks=[], @sought_type=Author, @attr_name="author", @name="author">, @instance=#<Library:0x00000002a1ebc0 ...>, @default_namespac
e=nil>, #<ROXML::XMLObjectRef:0x00000002a1eaf8 @opts=#<ROXML::Definition:0x00000002a373c8 @default=nil, @to_xml=nil, @name_explicit=false, @
cdata=nil, @required=nil, @frozen=nil, @wrapper=nil, @namespace=nil, @accessor="book", @array=true, @blocks=[], @sought_type=Book, @attr_nam
e="book", @name="book">, @instance=#<Library:0x00000002a1ebc0 ...>, @default_namespace=nil>]>
```

Is there a way I can remove `@roxml_references` from object created ??

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Show us a minimal example of your code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan added sample code

Comment: That helps. Now show us what things you've tried to fix the problem. If you haven't tried, why? If you searched multiple places but didn't find any information show us where you searched and why those didn't help. Remember, SO isn't a "write code for me site". We help you fix the code you can't make work, but we expect some evidence of your effort and labor toward solving the problem. We can see where you encountered it, but not where you tried to fix it. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: @theTinMan I have added approach that I have tried with Nokogiri, but somehow "\n" still appear in output.

Comment: `NOBLANKS` uses the libxml2 library to try to remove blanks during parsing, which is what the link in my answer discusses. You can't count on using `NOBLANKS` and instead have to manually remove the text nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still can't find a solution after searching the documentation and consulting the author of the gem, then let Nokogiri parse the output, delete the nodes and re-output it without indentation.

Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<root>
</root>
EOT

Nokogiri::XML(xml)
# => #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3ffd49419494 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ffd49419084 name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ffd49418df0 "\n">]>]>
```

Notice the Nokogiri::XML::Text node containing "\n" above. That's the line-end after `<root>` in the XML:

```
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root>\n</root>\n"
```

Here's how we find the text nodes:

```
doc.search('//text()') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff88c18d20 "\n">]
```

`'//text()'` is an XPath selector that means "search the entire document for text nodes.

We can walk through the DOM and delete just those empty nodes:

```
doc.search('//text()').each do |text_node|
  text_node.unlink 
end

doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root/>\n"
```

We have to be careful though, because a Nokogiri::XML::Text node can contain more than just the trailing line-end so indiscriminate node deletion will remove desired text too. We can also delete the node's contents, making it empty which works:

```
xml = <<EOT
<root>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</root>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search('//text()') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff77201927c "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff772018e80 "bar">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff772018c14 "\n">]
doc.search('//text()').each do |text_node|
  text_node.content = '' 
end

doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root><foo></foo></root>\n"
```

But notice that deleted the desired text "bar". The solution is to be more selective:

```
doc.search('//text()').each do |text_node|
  text_node.content = '' if text_node.content.strip.empty?
end

doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root><foo>bar</foo></root>\n"
```

Note: Nokogiri includes a `NOBLANKS` parsing option, which is designed to help remove the indentation nodes, but according to "[Unexpected behavior with XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2009-December/msg00019.html)", the underlying libXML2 library will not ignore blanks if it thinks that'd result in an invalid DOM being returned.

If you don't want the XMLdecl, you can tell Nokogiri to parse the document as a DocumentFragment:

```
xml = <<EOT
<root>
</root>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root>\n</root>\n"

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)
doc.to_xml # => "<root>\n</root>\n"
```

Comment: I have created xml from object using Nokogiri as you suggested, but when I tried to convert it back to xml, it gives roxml_references instance variable. I have added sample code to question for the same. Any idea on how can I skip this?

Comment: Use `to_xml` to convert it to XML from an `inspect` output?

Comment: I din't get you. I have added sample code or converting xml to object using `from_xml` and object that I am getting as @roxml_references. Is there a way I can prevent it?